# Qt eventFilter passes event to target, although it should be filtered

Tags: qt, qt5, mousewheel, eventfilter

my eventFilter doesn't work as expected. I either missunderstood its behaviour or I have a problem in my program.
In my program I have a QScrollArea with a QLabel inside to display an Image (just like in the Qt Image Viewer Example), but if the user scrolls his MouseWheel I don't want the ScrollArea to scroll, but the Image to scale. Therefore I implemented an eventFilter for my Label and my ScrollArea.

```
bool RBDP::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (target == scrollArea || target == iv) {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Wheel) {
            QWheelEvent *w = static_cast<QWheelEvent *>(event);
            iv->scaleImage(w->delta());
            return true;
        }
```

I know that the eventFilter actually gets triggered when you scroll. The problem is that the ScrollArea ALSO scrolls, i.e. if you use your MouseWheel, the Image scales and the ScrollArea scrolls!
As far as I know, the event shouldn't be propagated to its original target, if the eventFilter returns true.
I installed in my main class eventFilters for both, the scrollArea and iv (which is my QLabel).

```
scrollArea->installEventFilter(this);
iv->installEventFilter(this);
```

**How do I prevent the ScrollArea from scrolling?** I know this isn't much code, but the program is kind of complex already and I don't know, what else could be useful. So please let me know, if you need to see other code segments.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried adding `event->ignore()` ? If this works please tell me I will add some explanation then in an answer.

Comment: Maybe the event *is* filtered, but the QScrollArea also has an event filter which runs before yours. And, by the way, you should install the event filter on the QScrollArea's `viewport()`.

Comment: @Hayt event->ignore() did not work for me unfortunately.

Comment: @peppe You were kinda right. You need to apply the filter to 'scrollArea->viewport()'. Maybe it wasn't exactly what you are saying, but your hint about the viewport brought me here: link ;-) So thank you. It works for me